# Android Jetpack Compose - Image can't scale to box's width and Height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Created ImageCard view for creating the list in android jetpack compose
but some images can't scratch to Box widget's width and height.

Using 640*427 image and output like image 1.
Using 6720*4480 image and it's looking good like image 2.
Use below code to create ImageCard.
Usage of ImageCard function: Call ImageCardData function in setContent{} function

```
@Composable
fun ImageCard(
    painter: Painter,
    title: String,
    contentDescription: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        elevation = 5.dp
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painter,
                contentDescription = contentDescription,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                Color.Transparent,
                                Color.Black
                            ),
                            startY = 50f
                        )
                    )
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(12.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = title,
                    style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ImageCardData() {
    val painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.engagement)
    val title = "Sample Text Title"
    val description = "This is sample Image Description"
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        ImageCard(
            painter = painter,
            title = title,
            contentDescription = description
        )
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Your image view size gets calculated by it content, because it doesn't have any size modifiers.

Add `fillMaxSize` to the image:

```
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentDescription = contentDescription,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
```

Answer (score 22):

It depends by the [`Image`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#image_2) implementation with a `Painter`

> Creates a composable that lays out and draws a given `Painter`. This will attempt to **size the composable according to the `Painter`'s intrinsic size**. However, an optional `Modifier` parameter can be provided to adjust sizing or draw additional content (ex. background)

It means that using an 640*427 image in a parent container with larger dimensions the `Image` composable size is the original size of the `Painter`.
The scale factor applied by the `ContentScale` is based on these dimensions and source = destination and doesn't change the intrinsic size of the original Painter.

```kotlin
Image(
  painter = painter,
  contentDescription = contentDescription,
  contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```

[image]

Using a 6720*4480 image the `Image` size is larger than the parent container and in this way the `Image` composable fills all the available space.

In your case you can solve using the modifier `fillMaxWidth()` in your `Image`

```kotlin
Image(
  modifier =Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
  painter = painter,
  contentDescription = contentDescription,
  contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```

In this way the `Image` composable fills the parent space.

[image]